# maven dependency:purge-local-repository causing dependency resolution errors

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies

- I have a parent Jenkins job (`my-build-all`) that invokes 2 child-maven-build-jobs (`my-services` followed by `my-internal-api`) in serial (wait for previous to finish before starting next).
- Both builds happen on same machine and they share the local repo.
- `my-internal-api` depends on `my-services`.
- `my-internal-api` is built with goals: `dependency:purge-local-repository clean install`.
- `my-internal-api` fails with `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:purge-local-repository (default-cli) on project my-internal-api: Failed to refresh project dependencies for: com.kashyap:my-internal-api:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT: required artifacts missing:....com.kashyap:my-services:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT....for the artifact:....com.kashyap:my-internal-api:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT`
- I know for sure that at the end of `my-services` job, snapshot jar was built and pushed to Artifactory.

Here is the log from `my-services` build:

```
[main] INFO org....ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ my-services ---
[main] INFO org....PlexusContainer - Installing /home/ec2-user/workspace/my/Test/1. my-service/target/my-services-1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/kashyap/my-services/1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT/my-services-1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[main] INFO org....PlexusContainer - Installing /home/ec2-user/workspace/my/Test/1. my-service/dependency-reduced-pom.xml to /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/kashyap/my-services/1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT/my-services-1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[main] INFO org....BuildInfoClientBuilder - Deploying artifact: http://artifactory.xxx.local/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/kashyap/my-services/1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT/my-services-1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[main] INFO org....BuildInfoClientBuilder - Deploying artifact: http://artifactory.xxx.local/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/kashyap/my-services/1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT/my-services-1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[main] INFO org....ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org....ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD SUCCESS
[main] INFO org....ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org....ExecutionEventLogger - Total time: 35.123 s
[main] INFO org....ExecutionEventLogger - Finished at: 2018-05-03T20:18:21+00:00
[main] INFO org....ExecutionEventLogger - Final Memory: 37M/432M
[main] INFO org....ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] stage (Push Artifactory)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage Push Artifactory
Proceeding
[Pipeline] publishBuildInfo
Deploying build info to: http://artifactory.xxx.local/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://artifactory.xxx.local/artifactory/webapp/builds/my%20::%20Test%20::%201.%20my-service/125
```

It works fine when I:

- run with `-U clean install` instead OR
- start the jenkins job to build `my-internal-api` from the Jenkins UI.

Here is the log excerpt:

```
Started by upstream project "my/Test/0. my-build-all" build number 5
+ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /home/ec2-user/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.37.amzn1.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.23-31.54.amzn1.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
Artifactory integration is enabled
[6. my-internal-api-mainline] $ java -classpath /home/ec2-user/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar -Dmaven.home=/home/ec2-user/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3 -DbuildInfoConfig.propertiesFile=/tmp/buildInfo2752604435492193670.properties -Dm3plugin.lib=/home/ec2-user/cache/artifactory-plugin/2.10.3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/tmp/classworlds7843212232814826583conf "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/ec2-user/workspace/my/Test/6. my-internal-api-mainline" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f pom.xml -X dependency:purge-local-repository clean install
[main] DEBUG org....DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Skipped remote request for com.kashyap:my-services:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally installed metadata up-to-date.
[main] DEBUG org....ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - [buildinfo] Resolved artifact: com.kashyap:my-services:pom:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT:project from: /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository (enhanced) Context is: project
[main] DEBUG org....DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Skipped remote request for com.kashyap:my-services:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally installed metadata up-to-date.
[main] DEBUG org....ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - [buildinfo] Resolved artifact: com.kashyap:my-services:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT:project from: /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository (enhanced) Context is: project
[main] INFO org....PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo - Purging artifact: com.kashyap:my-services:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT
[main] INFO org....PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo - Deleting: /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/kashyap/my-services/1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT

[main] DEBUG org....DefaultArtifactResolver -   com.kashyap:my-services:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile (selected for compile)
[main] DEBUG org....ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - [buildinfo] Could not resolve artifact: com.kashyap:my-services:pom:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT:project
[main] INFO org....plugin.dependency.PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo - Could not find artifact com.kashyap:my-services:pom:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo - Resolving artifact: com.kashyap:my-services:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT
[main] DEBUG org....ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - [buildinfo] Could not resolve artifact: com.kashyap:my-services:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT:project
[main] INFO org....plugin.dependency.PurgeLocalRepositoryMojo - Could not find artifact com.kashyap:my-services:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT
[main] ERROR org....cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org....plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:purge-local-repository (default-cli) on project my-internal-api: Failed to refresh project dependencies for: com.kashyap:my-internal-api:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT: required artifacts missing:
[main] ERROR org....cli.MavenCli - com.kashyap:my-services:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT
[main] ERROR org....cli.MavenCli - for the artifact:
[main] ERROR org....cli.MavenCli - com.kashyap:my-internal-api:jar:1.0-r0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Any idea why maven is:

- finding local snapshot version of `my-services` to be up to date
- purging/deleting it and then
- complaining that it couldn't resolve it (though I think it's during the re-resolution as part of `purge-local-repository` goal, not as part of `compile` goal).

Comment: If your builds share a local repo, you need to make sure that they never run in parallel (local repos are not thread safe in any way). Did you consider that?

Comment: @JFMeier yes. Also it's clear front logs that previous build completed and jar was present in local repo and was deleted by maven.

Comment: You build `my-services` with `clean deploy`, i.e. you deploy it to your company Nexus/Artifactory?

Comment: @JFMeier yes. Built with clean install.

Comment: If you use `clean install`, the jar only goes to the _local_ repository and will be deleted by your purge command. Then it is gone and cannot be resolved. You need to use `clean deploy` to deploy it to an artifact repository.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know that. Though it's not the problem in this case. I don't know why but the jar and pom are deployed to artifactory during maven build. I see it in logs (OP updated). I had also verified in artifactory that the snapshot jar existed after `my-internal-api` build fails. `my-services` build clearly is skipping the step to fetch it (see logs) from artifactory because "locally installed metadata up-to-date".

Comment: Difficult: You are sure that the artifactory repository you are deploying to is the same where the dependencies are drawn from? Maybe your local repository is broken and you should delete its contents manually.

Comment: @JFMeier, yes. Has me stumped too. Yes the artifactory is the same (I can see all other dependencies being drawn from there). Local repo is on a Jenkins box, which is on EC2 in AWS and gets deleted if not used for a few hours. So the whole machine is recreated roughly everyday (which purges the local repo).